# VLOOKUP to Copy Column Data from Tables

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use vlookup on 4 separate tables (Table1:4) in the same sheet ("DataNew"). These 4 tables have 2 columns each (Emp_Name and a different column in each table). I want to use the vlookup to copy the send column from Table2:4 and paste it in Table1 as the 3rd, 4th and 5th columns. Table 4 might or might not have a 2nd column. In that case, I want the 4th column in Table1 to have values 0 in column E.

Comment: You need to do some work, share your code attept, load a screen-shots of your data (to better understand which columns you want to `VLookup` at)

Comment: Do you just want to copy the 2nd columns of Table 2,3, 4 to Table1 or you want to find for a matching value of Table1's Column1 in other tables column1 and display corresponding 2nd column value? It would be great if you can so some sample data with possible input and your expected output.

Comment: To match emp_name on each of these 4 tables (always the first column in each table) and update corresponding values in table1

Comment: Code Snippet:
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8htb6Hhczb5SEUyU3R4T2RZMW8/view?usp=sharing

Data:
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8htb6Hhczb5QU1mRkFiTmlNVW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ShaiRado - Screenshots updated.

Comment: @Siva- Screenshots updated.

Comment: For Each c In Sheets("Suspects").Range("A1", Sheets("Suspects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
              FR = 0
              On Error Resume Next
              FR = Application.Match(c, Sheets("Suspects").Columns("A"), 0)
              On Error GoTo 0
              If FR <> 0 Then Sheets("PT_Data").Range("B" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, 1)
            Next c